# Is it possible to create a self signed certificate in iOS?

Tags: ios, security, rsa, public-key-encryption

Is it possible to create a self signed certificate in iOS ? And is it possible to extract the public key from public key certificate created on server and store in Keychain?

Comment: These are separate questions. Please split them so that future searchers can find what they're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Apple documented process to generate your certificate.

Extracting keys from the keychain is ok.